# Conditional output in dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I want to build a dropdown menu showing teachers who teach certain instruments (see image below)

[image]

The dropdown component is this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { BiChevronDown } from "react-icons/bi";

import StaffList from "./StaffList"


const rows = [
    {
    id: 1,
    title: "Verantwortliche",
    },
    {
    id: 2,  
    title: "Lehrende der Streichinstrumente",
    instrument: "streichinstrumente"
    },
    {
    id: 3,  
    title: "Lehrende der Zupfinstrumente",
    },
    {
    id: 4,  
    title: "Lehrende des Tasteninstruments",
    },
    {
    id: 5,  
    title: "Lehrende des Gesangs",
    },
    {
    id: 6,  
    title: "Lehrende des Schlagzeugs",
    },
    {
    id: 7,  
    title: "Lehrende des Akkordeons",
    },
    {
    id: 8,  
    title: "Lehrende der Musiktheorie",
    },
    {
    id: 9,  
    title: "Lehrende der Früherziehung",
    }
]


class DropDownRows extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: false};
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    }
    
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="dropdown-rows">
        {rows.map(row => (
            <div key={row.id}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">{row.title}</div>
                <div className="col">
                <BiChevronDown
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    style={{float: "right"}}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.isToggleOn ? <StaffList /> : ''}
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default DropDownRows
```

it uses this StaffList component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"


function StaffList({ data }) {
    return(
    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
        query staffQuery {
        allMdx {
            edges {
            node {
                excerpt(pruneLength: 900)
                id
                body
                frontmatter {
                title
                description
                featuredImage {
                    childImageSharp {
                    gatsbyImageData(
                        placeholder: BLURRED
                    )
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }       
        `}

        render={data => (
        <div className="staff-container">
        {data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => (
        <article>
            <div className="staff-image-container">
            <GatsbyImage key={edge.node.id} alt='some alt text' image={getImage(edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage)} style={{margin: "0 auto", padding: "0"}} />
            </div>
            <div style={{margin: "0 2em"}}>
            <div>
                <h4 key={edge.node.id} style={{margin: "0"}}>{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h4>
                <h5>{edge.node.frontmatter.description}</h5>
            </div>
            <p><MDXProvider>{edge.node.excerpt}</MDXProvider></p>
            </div>
        </article> 
        ))}
        </div>
    )}
    />
    )
}



export default StaffList
```

this is one of the .mdx files i source my data from:

```
---
title: Diana Abouem à Tchoyi
featuredImage: Foto_07.jpg
description: Violine, Streicherklassen
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Right now the component looks like this:

[image]

How would I conditionally render the content for each bar. so not all bars opening with the same content but just the one clicked showing only those teachers who fall in the selected category. My idea is to have some sort of conditional statement, comparing the selected bar title with maybe a field in the teachers markdown file? Like

```
title: Hanna
category: Streichinstrumente
```

and then `if (allMdx.edges.node.frontmatter.category === rows.title) {...}`

That's as far as I can wrap my head around this. Maybe someone can help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would have one array of objects storing teachers' datas. Example below.

```html
const teacherData = [
  { id: 'piano',
    name: "Alex",
    otherData: ...
  },
  ... (similarly for the rest)
]
```

Then another array of objects/records for instrument-teachers. Such as:

```html
const records = [
  {
  id: 'piano',
  teacher: []
  }
]
```

After this I would loop through each element in the teacherData array to get the finalized record Array with id being the type of instrument and teachers being all the teachers that play that type of instruments.

Now, getting into the display part. I would write my component as below:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState([])
  
  function handleClick(id) {
    if show.includes(id) {
      const newShow = show.filter(a => a !== id)
      setShow(newShow)
    } else {
      const newShow = show.push(id)
      setShow(newShow)
    }    
  }
  return (
  <div className="dashboard">
    {records.map((record) => 
      (
      <div className="instrument-wrapper">
      <p onClick={() => handleClick(record.id)} >{record.id}</p> //The name of the instrument
      {show.includes(record.id) ?  (
        <div> 
        ... all the teachers here by mapping through the record.teachers
        </div>
      ) : (null)}
      <div>
      )
    )}
  </div>
  )
}
```